# Using Google Maps in ASP.Net Webforms - map not displaying

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps

I am a beginner to .NET programming and I am trying to put a Google Map in my code. This is a user control that I have inside a MultiView I am following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V-for-ASP-NET) but I cannot get it to work. Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong? I have looked at similar SO questions but did not find a solution - I specify my div width and height, call the initialize function on page load, etc. I get no compilation errors - everything works just fine and the div is there, it just does not load the map. I tried putting "runat=server" in the script tag but that gave me a compilation error.

Relevant code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StoreView.ascx.cs" Inherits="Practice.StoreView" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdStoreName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdStateCode" runat="server" />
<div>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnBackToStatePage" Text="Back to state" OnClick="btnBackToStatePage_Click" /></div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblStorePageHeader" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label></div>
<div>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgStorefront" ImageUrl="" /></div>
<head>
<title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        } 

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; float: right;">
    </div> 
</body>
```

EDIT I just tried to just render the map by itself in an HTML page, shown below, and it did not show up there either. The words "This is a page" do show up, but not the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span>This is a page.</span>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; float: right;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The network tab upon viewing the ASPX page that should contain my map:
[image]

The network tab upon viewing the HTML page that should contain the map:
[image]

Comment: You wouldn't use `runat="server"` for a script. You only do that for C# (or VB) code that you want to embed in the ASPX (which isn't a good practice). Check your browser's network and JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: @mason I have checked the JS console and there are no errors displayed - it is completely blank. Should there be something there at all? I have never used this tool before.

Comment: Look in the network tab and see if anything is communicating with Google's servers.

Comment: why the buttons and the first divs are out side the body ? and where is the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration before the `html` tag ? and where is the `html` tag ?

Comment: @Aristos because this is a ASP.NET webforms page, not an html page.

Comment: @mason I am not seeing anything that looks google-related, just some stuff from ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd

Comment: You *will* see something attempting to load form Google's servers since you have a script that pulls down from there. Look closer at the network tab of your browser's debugging tools.

Comment: @mason I have added a screencap of my network tab in Chrome. I am unsure what I should be looking for, but I don't see anything from Google. Am I wrong?

Comment: @shinytinsmile Are you sure that screenshot is what you see when you request the page that has the Google Map on it? What you should see is the browser pulling down the script from `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false`. If you don't see that, then of course you're not going to see the Google Map on your page. And if it did pull it down, you probably need to call your `initialize()` function, otherwise it's not going to run your code.

Comment: @mason This screenshot is what I see when I click a LinkButton that triggers the change of my MultiView. In the new view, I load a user-defined control which is the .ascx file I have posted in my question, which is where I want my map displayed. I call `initialize()` in the <body> tag on my .ascx page. Currently the view changes and everything else in the user control renders just fine - there is just an empty div where the map should be

Comment: You need to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Minimal means you need to cut out everything except exactly what you're working on. That means no Multi View, no link button, no anything else. Just the maps code. Best to just do a .html file. Then access that page and monitor your browser's network tool as you access that page. Monitor your browser's Network and Console tabs fors anything related to Google's servers or any other error. If your script has been declared properly, you *will* see the HTTP GET to their server in the Network tab.

Comment: @mason Take a look at my question - I have tried this since someone suggested it in their answer, and it still did not work. I just added a network tab screenshot. It is definitely communicating with Google's servers but still no map.

Comment: The last code block in your question has no calls to `initialize()` function. You'll need one somewhere. You can do it in the `onload` attribute of the body like in Nejdi's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript function works because I tried it and it shows the map. Maybe you are missing something else?

This is my exact page and 
[![It shows this up
 ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQrU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQrU.png)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="main.aspx.cs" Inherits="HelpAspx.main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
           var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
   <form runat="server">
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdStoreName" runat="server" />
       <asp:HiddenField ID="hdStateCode" runat="server" />
       <div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <asp:Label ID="lblStorePageHeader" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large"></asp:Label>
       </div>
       <div>
           <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgStorefront" ImageUrl="" />
       </div>
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; float: right;">
       </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I put my ASP controls inside a form tag inside the body as you have done, the view no longer loads. This file is .ascx.

Comment: I tried putting just the google maps script inside a regular HTML file and it did not render there either. See my edited question for the code.